# How to set css property according to css property of other element

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am using ionic 4 and want to set some mask element above other element.
My mask element is a fixed image that I want to set just above the ion-tab-bar - it means that I want my image "bottom" css property will be just the same as the ion-tab-bar css "height" property value.

I have already tried this inside the tabs page:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    document.getElementById('mask').style.bottom = document.getElementById('tabsbar').style.height;
}
```

But the style property returned empty fields...

Is there some other way? maybe with ngStyle?

Comment: `element.style.height` will only return a value if it were set using inline style. [`get​Computed​Style()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) will likely be what you need

Comment: @LGSon is right, but looking at your code I think you want to look for something other than `bottom` if you are looking for detecting something in view you may want checkout `getBoundingClientRect()` and the `bottom` property it returns.

Comment: Thanks @BugsArePeopleToo & @LGSon!
I solved it this way:

document.getElementById('mask').style.bottom = document.getElementById('tabsbar').getBoundingClientRect().height+'px';

(Inside the ionViewDidEnter method)

Answer (score 0):

you could go the jquery way:

```js
function hallo(){
    $("#num1").css("bottom", $("#num2").css("height")); 
}
```

```css
#num1{
position: absolute;
bottom: 100px;
background-color: red;
padding: 15px;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
}
#num2{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 100px;
background-color: green;
padding: 15px;
width: 100px;
height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="num1">
</div>
<div id="num2">

<button onclick="hallo();">I position red div at bottom: 150px</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this way:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {

  document.getElementById('mask').style.bottom = document.getElementById('tabsbar').getBoundingClientRect().height+'px';

}
```